# .htaccess file - Rewrite rules not working with new hosting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been using the following in the root of my hosting with (123-reg) for sometime now i have since moved to Godaddy and the rules not longer seem to work. I have contacted their support and they said that they follow the defaults for linux mod-rewrite rules and they believe there is a problem with my scripting...?

here is what i am using:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^fishing/$ fishing.php [L]
```

I have alot more rules within .htaccess but will pick this one just as an example.

When i was with 123-reg i could simply type in http://domain.com/fishing and it would load the fishing.php file.

On godaddy this goes straight to 404. Can anyone see anything obvious going on here?

For info: It works fine if i type in the full path: http://domain.com/fishing.php but this is not what i want.

Also can anyone confirm that this is a standard rewrite rule and should work with the defaults of apache mod-rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out for some reason you have to add:

```
    Options -Multiviews
```

to your .htaccess file for it to work.

Would be helpful if the techs at GoDaddy knew this information though. I have seen this on many forums on the internet about a similar problem with godaddy. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This is interesting because I tried it on my own Apache and it doesn't work, so I guess it is somehow related to GoDaddy's configuration. Anyway, your info will be helpful for others though.